# Array with {key: 'theKey', value: 'theValue'} objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object, openstreetmap

The OpeStreetMap API gives me tags in the following form (javascript syntax):

```
[{key: 'theKey1', value: 'theValue1'}, {key: 'theKey2', value: 'theValue2'} /* and so on*/];
```

Is there any way to get the value by the key without iterating all tags?

Comment: Did the API really return that JS literal instead of [JSON](http://json.org/)?

Comment: How could you find something if you don't search everywhere on your house since you don't sure where it was?

Comment: Not in the current form. As @Bergi mentioned if it actually is JSON (which I think it should be) then there are ways. Look for javascript JSON APIs.

Comment: It actually is a XML-File, but I converted it to JSON

Comment: @christianb: That's *not* JSON. Could you show us the original XML please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Every serialized format (XML, JSON, js literals, whatever) needs to be read step-by-step (iterated) until the desired key is found. This iteration might happen in the parse step or later when the parsed data structure is accessed, but there's no way around it.

If you eval that js literal or `JSON.parse` an equivalent JSON string, the resulting array does need to be looped over to find a specific key. However, you might transform it into a key-value lookup structure (object) by iterating it.

You only will be able to access the key directly if the OSM api allows you to search for it explicitly so that it is the only response.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do? Besides the [main API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) (which is mainly for editing, not for retrieving data!) there are several other APIs which return OSM data. For example the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) has a really extensive [query language](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) which allows you to do a lot of cool stuff and to create complex queries for retrieving specific data.